# Deserializing from JSON (ScriptObject) to Managed Object

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, serialization

I'm attempting to deserialize json returned from javascript via Silverlight.

Basically on the client side I am returning JSON and in my C# handler, I am getting it via ScriptObject...

I tried the ConvertTo method on the ScriptObject and still could not get anything.

How would I be able to convert a ScriptObject into a C# object that is a list of objects?

```
SomeCallBack(ScriptObject result) {

    // convert to managed object

    var objects = result.ConvertTo<List<SomeObjectClass>>(); // can't get any property from it..

    // however the count is correct...
    MessageBox.Show("count: " + objects.Count); // shows correct count of items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight contains no API to take a `ScriptObject` and serialise to a JSON string.

Silverlight supports JSON serialisation via the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer` class found in the `System.ServiceModel.Web` dll.

You will need to get some javascript base JSON serialiser to convert the value you are trying to pass as a `ScriptObject` so that you pass a JSON string parameter instead of a `ScriptObject`.  I believe the popular tool for this job is JQuery.

Now it looks like you were expecting a set (JSON like "[x1,x2,,,xn]") where x items are of type `SomeObjectClass`.  You can use this little generic function to deserialise such a list :-

```
    List<T> DeserializeJSON<T>(string json)
    {

        byte[] array = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(array);

        DataContractJsonSerializer dcs = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
        return (List<T>)dcs.ReadObject(ms);

    }
```

You would do:-

```
 var objects = DeserializeJSON<SomeObjectClass>(someJSON);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://json.codexplex.com/

They have a silverlight version, sounds like the Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning an actual JSON object, then you can actually use the ScriptObject.ConvertTo method to deserialize the JSON object directly into a C# object. For example, you could do:

**JSON Object**

```
{ id: 0001,
  name: 'some_name',
  data: [0.0, 1.0, 0.9, 90.0] }
```

**C# Object**

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;  // From the System.Runtime.Serialization assembly

[DataContract]
public struct JsonObj
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id;

    [DataMember]
    public string name;

    [DataMember]
    public double[] data;
}
```

**C# Callback**

```
public void SomeCallback(ScriptObject rawJsonObj)
{
    // Convert the object
    JsonObj jsonObj = rawJsonObj.ConvertTo<JsonObj>();
}
```

However, if you are returning a string that represents the JSON object, as opposed to an actual JSON object, then this will not work and you will have to use an alternate deserialization method. Refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645079(v=vs.95).aspx) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working just by **mimicking** JS objects by `C#` code. Interestingly enough it even allowed for objects literals to be used on a JS side (see `Collection` items, they are just object literals - nice move - indeed JS is the driver!).

SL Code (I pass a `JS` object into my `SL` component for processing):

```
[ScriptableMember()]
public string GetValue(ScriptObject o)
{

  Prototype p = (Prototype)o.ConvertTo<Prototype>();
  return "A";
}
```

JS:

```
control.Content.ExternalName.GetValue({ Collection: [{ a: "A1" }, { a: "A2"}] })
```

C#

```
public class Prototype
{  
  public List<PrototypeItem> Collection
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class PrototypeItem
{
  public string a
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```